# Very, very simple join query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to develop SQL code to display few information from a database that I have design. I have a question. Is an incorrect join in the query? Please advise.

```
  SELECT o.donutOrder_id, CONCAT(c.FirstName, ',', c.LastName) AS  ClientName,
 c.HomePhone, d.DonutName, d.DonutDescription, o.order_qty, d.DonutPrice,
 o.donut_orderTimestamp
 FROM donutOrder AS o
 INNER JOIN donut AS d ON d.donut_id = d.donut_id
 INNER JOIN customer AS c ON c.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

Here is the table schema:

```
           CREATE TABLE customer (
           customer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
           LastName VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
           FirstName VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
           Street VARCHAR (100) NULL,
           Apt  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
           City VARCHAR (225) NULL,
           State CHAR (2) NULL,
           Zip CHAR (10) NULL,
           HomePhone VARCHAR (20)  NULL,
           MobilePhone  VARCHAR (20) NULL,
           OtherPhone VARCHAR (20) NULL
           ) ENGINE = InnoDB;



     CREATE TABLE donut (
     donut_id  INT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (donut_id) ,
     DonutName  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
     DonutDescription VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
     DonutPrice DECIMAL (8,2) NOT NULL,
     DonutPhotoID VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL
     ) ENGINE = InnoDB;


    CREATE TABLE donutOrder
    (
    customer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    donut_id   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    donutOrder_id      INT NOT NULL,
    donut_orderTimestamp  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
     order_qty   INT NOT NULL,
    special_notes  VARCHAR(500) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (donut_id, customer_id),
   INDEX (customer_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (donut_id) REFERENCES donut (donut_id) 
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (customer_id)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Under what circumstances does 1 not equal 1?

Comment: What @Strawberry is trying to tell you is to look at the join conditions... you need to something like `ON o.donut_id = d.donut_id` and `ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id` because you are trying to relate these tables on a common id.  But without seeing your tables we can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answer. Your query was not logical, in that you were simply joining a field to itself.  I have not created the tables and embedded sample data so I cannot tell the result.  But joins work by equating common field(s) between tables.  Pick up a basic SQL book.

```
SELECT o.donutOrder_id, CONCAT(c.FirstName, ',', c.LastName) AS  ClientName,
 c.HomePhone, d.DonutName, d.DonutDescription, o.order_qty, d.DonutPrice,
 o.donut_orderTimestamp
 FROM donutOrder AS o
 INNER JOIN donut AS d ON o.donut_id = d.donut_id
 INNER JOIN customer AS c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
```